# 'cdk destroy' is not working as intended or I am not understanding it correctly?

Tags: aws-cdk

Here is my demo stack,

```
export class HelloCdkStack extends cdk.Stack {
  constructor(parent: cdk.App, id: string, props?: cdk.StackProps) {
    super(parent, id, props);
    new s3.Bucket(this, 'MyFirstBucket', {
      versioned: true,
      encryption: s3.BucketEncryption.KmsManaged,
    });
  }
}
```

'cdk deploy' creates a new bucket, but when I execute 'cdk destroy' it does not delete the bucket. Am I doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 11):

By default, S3 buckets are configured to be 'orphaned' when a stack is deleted. Setting [`removalPolicy`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-s3.Bucket.html#removalpolicy) to `Destroy` will physically destroy the bucket on deletion.

Comment: Also refer to this doc: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_core.RemovalPolicy.html

Comment: I think it will only delete if Destroy is set AND the bucket is empty

Comment: Yes this setting will destroy the bucket, but ONLY if it is empty. A feature request for non empty buckets is being tracked here: https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/3297

Answer (score 2):

You can set `destroy` to `removalPolicy`, it will remove the bucket if it's empty: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-s3.Bucket.html#removalpolicy

If you want to destroy even non-empty bucket, you should also set `autoDeleteObjects` property to `true`: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-s3.Bucket.html#autodeleteobjects

Comment: This is the correct answer for recent versions of CDK1 and 2

Answer (score 1):

If you need to automatically destroy a bucket with files in it, check out this CDK construct: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@mobileposse/auto-delete-bucket

If you need to automatically destroy a bucket that is expected to be empty, use the standard bucket and set removalPolicy to DESTROY. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-s3.Bucket.html#removalpolicy

Answer (score 1):

In my case the problem was, `cdk` was trying to fetch different accounts Credentials. Add the `--verbose` or `-v` flag to see if any exception is thrown internally.

It's a shame that the exception was not getting logged to stdout or stderr (as it should for any tool)

Answer (score 0):

In python, following the [getting started](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/getting_started.html), you can add `removal_policy=cdk.RemovalPolicy.DESTROY` parameter when instantiate the `s3.Bucket` object, so the bucket will be delete on `cdk destroy`.

```py
from aws_cdk import core as cdk
from aws_cdk import aws_s3 as s3


class HelloCdkStack(cdk.Stack):

    def __init__(self, scope: cdk.Construct, construct_id: str, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(scope, construct_id, **kwargs)
        bucket = s3.Bucket(self,
                           "MyFirstBucket",
                           versioned=True,
                           removal_policy=cdk.RemovalPolicy.DESTROY)  # delete bucket on destroy
```